# Another Capital puzzle (Initially Capitals)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

### Replace the "?" with the correct answer (all "?" unique). Explain why.

---

Astana Muscat Bangkok

Vilnius Quito Tegucigalpa

Riga Algiers Caracas

Cairo Washington DC Brussels

Luanda Montevideo Bishkek

Podgorica Male Saint John's

..... ..... .....

Santo Domingo Amsterdam Kabul

Roseau Vienna Bamako

..... ..... .....

Baku Jakarta Oslo

Lisbon Muscat Beijing

### A ?

### B ?

### C ?

### D ?

### E ?

### F ?

### G ?

### H ?

### I ?

### J ?

### K ?

### L ?

---

Comment: Hmmm... Pretty sure I've resolved all 10 of the given examples but just can't seem to work out how to fill the two '... ... ...' gaps. Presumably there's a sequence of some kind involved that allows those to be filled (and their answers derived) but I'm just not seeing it... I'm guessing that 'A' equates to the first row, and 'B' to the second, etc. but I guess there's no guarantee of that and we may also need to reorder these. Still thinking.

Comment: @Stiv Ok, you're close then. And yes, A equates to first, B to second, etc... It's like you say, once you see the pattern you'll know what needs to be filled in.

Comment: Oh! I've just spotted it :)

Comment: I don't really see the point of the "A ?, B ? ..." part. The puzzle is only about the 12 lines above it. And if you want to label those lines for whatever reason you could have just written "A. Astana Muscat Bangkok" directly

Comment: @Ivo You're right, I should've placed in front of the capitals aswell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several acceptable ways to replace the two series of dots in the puzzle. One would be to use:

> **Windhoek Jerusalem Nairobi** (for the first gap)
>
>  and
>
>  **Stockholm Kyiv Monaco** (for the second gap)

And doing so in combination with the existing capital city triplets would yield the solution:

> A. Japan; B. Finland; C. Malta; D. Argentina; E. Malaysia; F. Jordan; **G. Jamaica**; H. Andorra; I. Spain; **J. Oman**; K. Niger; L. Denmark.

Here's how this puzzle works... (Note that although not explicitly stated each time, all country and capital city names used in this puzzle are written in English.)

**Step 1a:**

> Find the countries of which each listed city is the capital:
>
>  A. Astana Muscat Bangkok → **Kazakhstan Oman Thailand**;
>  B. Vilnius Quito Tegucigalpa → **Lithuania Ecuador Honduras**;
>  C. Riga Algiers Caracas → **Latvia Algeria Venezuela**;
>  D. Cairo Washington DC Brussels → **Egypt USA Belgium**;
>  E. Luanda Montevideo Bishkek → **Angola Uruguay Kyrgyzstan**;
>  F. Podgorica Male Saint John's → **Montenegro Maldives Antigua&Barbuda**;
>  G. (blank)
>  H. Santo Domingo Amsterdam Kabul → **Dominican Republic Netherlands Afghanistan**;
>  I. Roseau Vienna Bamako → **Dominica Austria Mali**;
>  J. (blank)
>  K. Baku Jakarta Oslo → **Azerbaijan Indonesia Norway**;
>  L. Lisbon Muscat Beijing → **Portugal Oman China**.

**Step 2a:**

> Reduce these country names to just their initial letters:
>
>  A. **K**azakhstan **O**man **T**hailand → **KOT**;
>  B. **L**ithuania **E**cuador **H**onduras → **LEH**;
>  C. **L**atvia **A**lgeria **V**enezuela → **LAV**;
>  D. **E**gypt **U**SA **B**elgium → **EUB**;
>  E. **A**ngola **U**ruguay **K**yrgyzstan → **AUK**;
>  F. **M**ontenegro **M**aldives **A**ntigua&Barbuda → **MMA**;
>  G. (blank)
>  H. **D**ominican Republic **N**etherlands **A**fghanistan → **DNA**;
>  I. **D**ominica **A**ustria **M**ali → **DAM**;
>  J. (blank)
>  K. **A**zerbaijan **I**ndonesia **N**orway → **AIN**;
>  L. **P**ortugal **O**man **C**hina → **POC**.

**Step 3a:**

> Reverse these three-letter sequences, and identify **the only world capital city that begins with these three letters**:
>
>  A. **KOT** → **TOK**yo;
>  B. **LEH** → **HEL**sinki;
>  C. **LAV** → **VAL**letta;
>  D. **EUB** → **BUE**nos Aires;
>  E. **AUK** → **KUA**la Lumpur;
>  F. **MMA** → **AMM**an;
>  G. (blank)
>  H. **DNA** → **AND**orra La Vella;
>  I. **DAM** → **MAD**rid;
>  J. (blank)
>  K. **AIN** → **NIA**mey;
>  L. **POC** → **COP**enhagen.

**Step 4a:**

> Convert the capital cities into their corresponding countries and note the starting letters of these country names:
>
>  A. Tokyo → **J**apan;
>  B. Helsinki → **F**inland;
>  C. Valletta → **M**alta;
>  D. Buenos Aires → **A**rgentina;
>  E. Kuala Lumpur → **M**alaysia;
>  F. Amman → **J**ordan;
>  G. (blank)
>  H. Andorra La Vella → **A**ndorra;
>  I. Madrid → **S**pain;
>  J. (blank)
>  K. Niamey → **N**iger;
>  L. Copenhagen → **D**enmark.

Now a pattern emerges - these letters are also...

> ...the first letters of the **twelve months of the year** (in English).
>
>  A. **J**apan → **J**anuary;
>  B. **F**inland → **F**ebruary;
>  C. **M**alta → **M**arch;
>  D. **A**rgentina → **A**pril;
>  E. **M**alaysia → **M**ay;
>  F. **J**ordan → **J**une;
>  G. (blank)
>  H. **A**ndorra → **A**ugust;
>  I. **S**pain → **S**eptember;
>  J. (blank)
>  K. **N**iger → **N**ovember;
>  L. **D**enmark → **D**ecember.

**Filling the gaps:**

So now we can work backwards from this endpoint to work out what should have appeared in the two blank spaces...

> **Step 4b:** Since we are missing the entries for July and October, we need a country beginning with 'J' and another beginning with 'O'. Since we are instructed that all the '?' icons must be unique and we have already used Japan and Jordan, the only 'J'-country that remains is **Jamaica**; also, there is only one country whose English name begins with 'O': **Oman**. Their respective capital cities are **Kingston** and **Muscat**.
>
>  **Step 3b:** Take the first 3 letters of these cities and reverse them to get **NIK** and **SUM**.
>
>  **Step 2b:** Choose triplets of countries beginning with these initial letters. For example:
>
>  **NIK**: **N**amibia **I**srael **K**enya
>  **SUM**: **S**weden **U**kraine **M**onaco
>
>  **Step 1b:** Replace these countries with their capital cities, giving us the starting triplets of:
>
>  **Windhoek Jerusalem Nairobi**
>
>  and
>
>  **Stockholm Kyiv Monaco**
>
>  as suggested in the first spoiler!

<sup>Two final notes of interest:</sup>

> <sup>Note that Jamaica *had* to be used in this reverse-puzzling step rather than clued by an initial triplet in the puzzle set-up, as the first 3 letters of Jamaica's capital, **KIN**gston, also begin the name of the capital of Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, **KIN**gstown, and we would have had an ambiguous step!</sup>
>
>  <sup>Also note that the capital of Kazakhstan is indeed 'Astana' once more, after the Kazakh Parliament reversed its name change to 'Nur-Sultan' in September this year. The city currently holds the Guinness World Record for most name changes - [five in six decades](https://www.economist.com/asia/2022/09/29/guess-which-city-holds-the-record-for-the-most-name-changes)!</sup>

Comment: That's it! Well done :)